# sending array to shader with glUniformMatrix

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I have a model with for which all `matdex`s (read matrix index) are either 0, 1, and 2 roughly evenly distributed.  `bonebends[matdex[whichvertex]]` tells us which matrix should be used on this vertex.
initializing, c++:

```
std::vector< GLint >  matdex; //initialized to 0, 1, or 2 for each vertex loaded, not shown for brevity
std::vector<glm::mat4> bonebends;
int frames=0;
bonebends.push_back(glm::mat4(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)); //identity matrices initially
bonebends.push_back(glm::mat4(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1));
bonebends.push_back(glm::mat4(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)); // thats 3 bones
ver_ind = glGetAttribLocation(shaderID, "VER_IND");
boneID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, "BONE_MATRIX[0]");
glGenBuffers(1, &ind_buff);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ind_buff);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, matdex.size() * sizeof(GLint), &matdex[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

periodically in main loop, c++:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3); //IND
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ind_buff);
glVertexAttribPointer( ver_ind, 1, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );
//ALSO LOOK HERE
glUniformMatrix4fv(boneID, 3 , GL_FALSE, &bonebends[0][0][0]);
frames+=1;
float cs=cos(3.14*2.0*(frames/100.0));
float sn=sin(3.14*2.0*(frames/100.0));
//  LOOK HERE
bonebends[0]=glm::mat4(
cs ,  0,-sn,0  ,
0 ,  1,  0,0  ,
sn,  0, cs,0  ,
0 ,  0,  0,1  );
```

in the shader, glsl:

```
layout(location = 3) in int VER_IND;
uniform mat4 BONE_MATRIX[3];
```

in the main function of shader, glsl:

```
gl_Position =  BONE_MATRIX[VER_IND] * vec4(VER_POS,1); //VER_POS is the vertex's coordinates
```

I hoped this would make all the vertices with a coinciding `matdex` of 0 to rotate, and the rest remain stationary. Instead this displays the model (which is otherwise rendered correctly) spinning, as if all `matdex`s values are equal to 0.  Which a little `cout`ing tells me they are not.  I don't know how to debug `VER_IND` in the shader.
 I tried

- using `uint` instead of `int` for all incarnations of `matdex`, which didn't make a difference.
- Changing `BONE_MATRIX[VER_IND]` to `BONE_MATRIX[0]` in shader, which made it crash(???)
- Changing the second and fourth argument of `glUniformMatrix4fv(boneID, 3 , GL_FALSE, &bonebends[0][0][0]);` in various ways, didn't help.
- changed `matdex`s values such that none of them were 0, and it still rotates as if the shader is only using `BONE_MATRIX[0]`.
- Changing the line below `//  LOOK HERE` to `bonebends[1]=glm::mat4(` results in the model not spinning at all.

From this I concluded that its only ever using the first of `BONE_MATRIX[3]`, probably because the shader isn't receiving it correctly. I can post the whole thing but its a bit lengthy.
 I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how to get information back from the shader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of problems.

First, `matdex` is *empty*. So you're not getting any actual information.

Second,

```
layout(location = 3) in int VER_IND;

glVertexAttribPointer( ver_ind, 1, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );
```

These two things *cannot* work together. `glVertexAttribPointer` can only feed floating-point inputs. If you use integer formats like `GL_INT`, [they will be converted to floats](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Component_type). If you want to feed integer inputs, you must use `glVertexAttribIPointer` (note the `I`).

Or just make `VER_IND` a float. And pass `GLubyte`s instead of `GLint`s. Really, there's no point in taking up all of that memory.

Third:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3); //IND
glVertexAttribPointer( ver_ind, 1, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );
```

The first parameter of both of these functions should be *the same*, if you're trying to enable `ver_ind`.

Fourth:

```
//ALSO LOOK HERE
glUniformMatrix4fv(boneID, 3 , GL_FALSE, &bonebends[0][0][0]);
```

I don't see where you use `glUseProgram` to set the program you wanted to change the uniform data on.

Fifth:

```
//  LOOK HERE
bonebends[0]=glm::mat4(
```

Changing a value *after* you have uploaded it does not magically cause the uploaded value to change.

There may be (and likely are) more problems, but the code you posted is incomplete and I don't intend to be your personal debugger. At the very least, start with code that you *know* works, then make the smallest change leading towards what you want. Get that working, then make another change. And so on. You did a bunch of stuff all at once, and it didn't work out.

Comment: As I said, this isn't my entire program, the description tells you what `matdex` is full of.  Opps hit enter, continued in next.

Comment: Fourth: I do use `glUseProgram`, its not shown, since its rendering that isn't the issue. Fifth: its changed after I uploaded it, but its a persistent variable inside a loop it doesn't matter where it happens after the first go around.  It renders and spins so these two aren't a problem.  I'm going to try what you said on "third" and "second".

Comment: @gunfulker: I cannot magically know whether the code you *haven't* shown works. I can't know whether the code you haven't shown even *exists*. Therefore, I can't know whether something you haven't shown isn't the problem. That's what happens when you don't post a full [SSCCE](http://sscce.org): people get the wrong idea about what's going wrong.

Comment: Suggestion 2 fixed it, thanks. Also for the advice about saving memory.  And your help with my previous post.  I can't "vote up" yet.

Comment: One more thing, is there a way to return values from the shader for debugging?

Comment: @gunfulker: Yes. Write them to the screen.

Comment: So no way to use the shader to make heavy decisions involving collisions or something?

Comment: @gunfulker: First, you asked about debugging shaders, not decision making and such. Second, that's a new question. And third, [generally you don't want to](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51309/regarding-physics-engines-and-the-gpu/51312#51312).

Comment: I only brought it up because the collision detection would have to make the results accessible to the CPU (like you say in the link, a CPU->GPU->CPU round trip) and if I knew how to access values I would have used it to determine that `matdex`->`VER_IND` was the problem.  It would destroy the asynchronicity but it would just be for diagnosis, not the final product.